# I could not access jupyterhub locally

Tags: docker, jupyter, jupyterhub

I have a docker image (jupyterhub)running locally.
when I try in browser localhost:8000 i get site can't reach issue.

docker ps shows;

Here is teh jupyterhub dockerimages' logs;

> ratha$ docker run -p 8000:8000 856b48323ac4

```
I 2019-09-17 00:40:38.690 JupyterHub app:2120] Using Authenticator: jupyterhub.auth.PAMAuthenticator-1.0.0
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:38.691 JupyterHub app:2120] Using Spawner: jupyterhub.spawner.LocalProcessSpawner-1.0.0
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:38.709 JupyterHub app:1257] Loading cookie_secret from /srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:38.755 JupyterHub proxy:460] Generating new CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN
[W 2019-09-17 00:40:38.756 JupyterHub app:1532] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2019-09-17 00:40:38.757 JupyterHub app:1534] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:38.757 JupyterHub app:1563] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[W 2019-09-17 00:40:38.804 JupyterHub app:1898] admin appears to have stopped while the Hub was down
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:38.816 JupyterHub app:2337] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[W 2019-09-17 00:40:38.817 JupyterHub proxy:516] Found proxy pid file: /srv/jupyterhub/jupyterhub-proxy.pid
[W 2019-09-17 00:40:38.817 JupyterHub proxy:528] Proxy no longer running at pid=11
[W 2019-09-17 00:40:38.819 JupyterHub proxy:642] Running JupyterHub without SSL.  I hope there is SSL termination happening somewhere else...
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:38.819 JupyterHub proxy:645] Starting proxy @ http://:8000
00:40:39.475 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxying http://*:8000 to (no default)
00:40:39.481 - info: [ConfigProxy] Proxy API at http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/routes
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:39.649 JupyterHub proxy:319] Checking routes
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:39.650 JupyterHub proxy:399] Adding default route for Hub: / => http://127.0.0.1:8081
[I 2019-09-17 00:40:39.654 JupyterHub app:2422] JupyterHub is now running at http://:8000

[I 2019-09-17 00:45:39.659 JupyterHub proxy:319] Checking routes
[I 2019-09-17 00:50:39.656 JupyterHub proxy:319] Checking routes
```

What is wrong, Same image running for others. Im trying it in docker  terminal in my MAC.

Comment: try run with paramter `docker run -p 8000:8000 -d --name jupyterhub jupyterhub/jupyterhub jupyterhub`

Comment: did you try accessing localhost 8081 and 8001? are you running a webapp on 8000 already?